# Visual Studio debug menu invisible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I feel a little stupid asking this, but the "Debug"-menu in my Visual Studio installation has disappeared. It supposed to be between the "Build" and "Tools" menu, but it is simply not there. Restarting VS doesn't help. Also tried looking for a way to customize the menus, but no success.

Any ideas where it went, and how I can get it back?

Comment: For anyone (like me), if you have imported any vs settings from previous versions or devices, then follow the marked answer for resolution. It works without disturbing other imported settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your menu -> Customize -> Select Menu Bar -> Click Reset button

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/3576/debugmenu.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/3576/debugmenu.png)

And make sure you're in debug mode :)

If this doesn't help try Tools menu -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings

Comment: Under the "Rearrange Commands" dialog, I can select different menus to customize and reset, but there is no Debug menu to select. Its as if the debug menu has been erased completely.

Comment: Aha. Thanks. I didn't think of the menu bar as being a toolbar, so I never looked under the "Toolbars" tab. Thanks!

Comment: "Right click on your menu?"  Doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @ChrisJ - I think what he meant is:
Right click on your Toolbar where "File, Edit, View ... " is -> Customize... -> Commands tab ->  Menu bar: select Menu bar from the drop down menu -> click: Reset All.

Answer (score 0):

[VS2015] - During reseting be sure to choose 'General' preset. If you choose for example web dev code only it still would be invisible.

Answer (score -2):

Inside the build menu drop down you will see the "Start Debug" submenu, you can start debugging by clicking "go" inside it. Or else you can press "F5" to start the debugging to see the Debug toolbar please follow the procedure given by Nokola.